# Criterion restrictions on objects

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x

This code is not valid but is it possible to this in a different way. I would like to use the String regnumber in the Car object in the Person object.

```
public class Person(){
    Car car;
}

public class Car(){
    String regnumber;
}

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
Criterion c = Restrictions.ilike("car.regnumber", search, MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to do this.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class).createAlias("car", "car");
```